# how to save image from url in core data so that I can show it even when net is off

Tags: ios, core-data

I am making an app in which I am storing array which contains images from url. I want to check the condition of net availability and status of core data. If net is reachable and core data has data then it should delete original data and replace it by new one.If there is no net connection then it should show existing core data. I have tried second case but my image is not coming. And in first case I am deleting data using:

```
[context deleteObject:newArray];           
NSError *error=nil;
[context save:&error];
```

then it is showing fault in console. Please can anyone help me?

Comment: check the net is reachable , by using if condition  u can check if net is available  load through JSON r else Load core data

Comment: i have checked net connections. the problem is that when there is no net connection i am not getting my image in image view from previous core data

Comment: check whether the data is storing or not

Comment: without net how can u fire the image url ...???

Comment: if u save images in NSData  .Then try this..  NSManagedObject *selectedObject = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[selectedObject valueForKey:@"image"]];
[[newCustomer yourImageView] setImage:image];

Comment: it is giving exception unrecognized selector sent to instance on UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[selectedObject valueForKey:@"image"]];

Comment: try this for save NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(yourUIImage);
[newManagedObject setValue:imageData forKey:@"image"];                          Then try retrieve this.. NSManagedObject *selectedObject = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]; UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[selectedObject valueForKey:@"image"]]; [[newCustomer yourImageView] setImage:image];

Comment: Is it working ? r not ..